Does \ttfamily override the effect of \hyphenchar?
Using the following MWE, the first paragraph is hyphenated, whereas the other two are not:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\textwidth=7cm % increase the likelihood of hyphenation

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\code[1]{{\ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=-1 #1}}
\code{x} \blindtext

\renewcommand*\code[1]{{\fontfamily\ttdefault\hyphenchar\font=-1 #1}}
\code{x} \blindtext

\renewcommand*\code[1]{{\hyphenchar\font=-1 #1}}
\code{x} \blindtext

\end{document}

I realize that the effect of \hyphenchar is global and that \hyphenchar\font=-1 should not be needed after \ttfamily in the first definition since by default LaTeX doesn't hyphenate typewriter type text. But then, why does the presence of \ttfamily disable the effect of \hyphenchar (and not \fontfamily\ttdefault)?

Yes, as per the second link in the question. But setting hyphenchar to -1 should disable hyphenation globally, not only in typewriter text, as seen in the second and third examples. The question is really: why isn't hyphenation turned off for the whole paragraph in the first case?

sorry yes I'd deleted my initial comment, misread the question. See answer posted instead

\fontfamily\ttdefault does not change the font, you need \fontfamily\ttdefault\selectfont
so
in the first example hyphenchar of the document font is not affected so hyphenation happens as normal.
In the second example due to the missing \selectfont the current font is the document font so that is accessed by \font and its hypenvhar is set to -1 and hyphenation is diabled
The third example is then a repeat of the second.
If you add \selectfont in the second case then the output is

as then the second case is like the first, hyphenation is disabled (again) for tt font, and the document font is not affected.

Ah, ok, now I get it! \font would stand for "the current font". In \ttfamily\hyphenchar\font=-1, the change in hyphenation applies to monospace text, but for the rest of the document, as \hyphenchar is global. Without \ttfamily (the third case), the change appies to the document font. The second case, I shouldn't have included in first place; I didn't check the output close enough to notice that the text was not in monospace. Thanks David!
